# Making if statement if the character in the index is equal to

Tags: python, string

How to make an if statement only giving the index of character in the string and if its equall to example

```
# i know this is wrong so plss help me
k = "klk"
if k[2] == "l":
    print("done")
```

If i print its only program finish

Comment: it's `print` and not `Print`.  your problem is unclear. what do you want your program to print here?

Comment: And index 2 is `'k'`.  Indexing is zero-based.

Comment: You should get more details of what exactly the expected and current output is. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Python indexes start at 0.

k[0] is `k`

k[1] is `l`

k[2] is `k`

You would need to do

```py
k = "klk"
if k[1] == "l":
    print("done")
```

You can also go in a reverse form with negative numbers:

```py
test = "hello"
if test[-2] == "l":
    print("done")
```

test[-1] is `o`

test[-2] is `l`

test[-3] is `l`

test[-4] is `e`

Answer (score -1):

```
k = input("enter example: ")
if k[1] == "l" and len(k) >= 2:
    print("k contains l")
```

I would highly recommend Tech With Tim's video "Python as fast as possible":
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VchuKL44s6E

Comment: This is a bad idea. Consider what would happen if the input was was fewer than two characters

Comment: what do you mean by *and index(k) >= 2* ? Perhaps you should try editing your answer to include that and see what happens

Comment: I'm sorry @ArthurKing, I was just giving an example...

Comment: You should try running your code before posting it. Try it with an input of fewer than 2 characters and see what happens. Hint: The *if* condition will be evaluated left to right